# Limit X-Axis AFTER applying grouping/series values

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a dataset, which has a list of article names, and a user.

eg.

```
Article  | User
Article1 | ABT
Article1 | ABT
Article2 | ABT
Article1 | MLH
Article2 | MLH
Article2 | MLH
```

and I have a dataset, which is preparing this in a count, so that the data looks like this:

```
Article  | User | Count
Article1 | ABT  | 2
Article2 | ABT  | 1
Article1 | MLH  | 1
Article2 | MLH  | 2
```

So you can see, I'm just counting the views for each article grouped by the user.

I want to present this in a stacked bar chart, so that the Article is the x-axis and the user is the series, so I can see the popularity of a given article and also see the popularity by user for that article.

eg. (can't post images)

[Example Stacked Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIGI0.jpg)

This works fine, and I have this already, but I want to restrict the actual amount of Articles displayed. I will end up having over 100 articles to display, so i'd like to restrict to top 10-20 articles, but in the same stacked format, so I can't just "TOP N" the dataset, as it could lose series data for a given article.

eg.

```
Article  | User | Count
Article1 | ABT  | 100
Article2 | ABT  | 98
Article1 | MLH  | 10
Article2 | MLH  | 2
```

Putting a "TOP 2" on this would lose series data for the MLH visits to each article.

Is there a way to restrict the X-Axis, after it is prepared for rendering for the chart? Or other solution i've completely missed.

Answer (score 0):

Add a filter to the Category Group (Article):

```
Expression: =Count(Fields!ArticleName.Value)
Operator: TOP N
Value : 10
```

returns top 10 for that category after all grouping is applied.